# FindFiles: lappend issue

Tags: tcl

I have written a procedure of FindFile.tcl. It will find .v, .sv and .vhd all the in all subdirectory and append to a list($tb_file). Anyhow it only append parts of them. Supposingly it should append all files.

```
Result: Test_Plan.sv Test_Plan_Copy.sv sim_driver_2.sv
Expected Result: Test_Plan.sv Test_Plan_Copy.sv sim_driver_1.sv sim_driver_2.sv
```

What i Find Out:
`$tb_file` will miss one element in the list before it goes to second foreach statement;

My FindFile.tcl

```
proc FindFiles { MY_TB_DIR tb_file } {
  set pwd [pwd];
  # set tb_file $tb_file
  set tb_file $tb_file
  # puts "after proc call testbench files are $tb_file"
  set MY_TB_DIR $MY_TB_DIR
  puts "after proc call tb_dir $MY_TB_DIR"
  set dir_file [glob -nocomplain -dir $MY_TB_DIR *];
  # puts $dir_file
  # set dir_file [glob -nocomplain *]

  foreach item $dir_file {
    set file [file tail $item];
    puts $file;
    switch -glob -- $file {
      *.v {lappend tb_file $file
        puts "Append $tb_file"
      }

      *.sv {lappend tb_file $file
        puts "Append $tb_file"
      }

      *.vhd {lappend tb_file $file
        # puts "Test bench file is $tb_file"
      }

      default {}
    };
    set tb_file $tb_file;
  };

  foreach item2 $dir_file {
    # recurse - go into the sub directory
    if { [file isdirectory $item2] } {
      set sub_dir [file join $MY_TB_DIR $item2] ;
      puts "\n\n before proc call $tb_file";
      puts " \n\n sub_dir $sub_dir";
      FindFiles $sub_dir $tb_file;
      # FindFiles $sub_dir
    }
  };
  # puts "Testbench are $tb_file"
  cd $pwd
}
```

Pls advice. Really appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Advice #1: Use tcllib fileutil::findByPattern does what you want... http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/fileutil.html

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that you want to accumulate files from subdirectories, yet you're not actually doing that. You're also not using the capabilities of `glob` well. Here's my take:

```
proc FindFiles {MY_TB_DIR {accumulate_var ""}} {
    if {$accumulate_var ne ""} {
        upvar 1 $accumulate_var result
    }
    foreach file [glob -nocomplain -dir $MY_TB_DIR -type f "*.{v,sv,vhd}"] {
        lappend result [file tail $file]
    }
    foreach dir [glob -nocomplain -dir $MY_TB_DIR -type d "*"] {
        FindFiles $dir result
    }
    return $result
}
```

<sup>(None of those glob terms actually need to be in double-quotes. I just did it for syntax highlighting!)</sup>

Comment: The real key is to use the power of `glob`; it does a lot for you. I could have also used the `-tails` option to it, except I don't really like that one. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't understood how process calls work in Tcl. You have several lines like this

```
set a $a
```

which just set the variable to its self. It also looks as if you are trying to update the parameters to the proc in the nested calls and expecting the results to be available in the parent proc. Tcl proc parameters don't work that way, you need to return a new list and join that to your results.

Comment: I have removed all the set a $a.  It still doesn't work.  Besides, the list appended in the 1st foreach lost when it reach 2nd foreach.